# codeigniter - use custom config value inside CI config file

Tags: codeigniter

I got custom.php (inside config folder) with code like below

```
$config['myurl'] = 'somesite.com';
```

I got config.php ( standard CI ), I want to set the base_url using the value from custom.php, like this

```
$config['base_url'] = $this->config->item('myurl');
```

Doing that I got the error

```
Using $this when not in object context in /Volumes/HD 2/work/vnl/app/config/config.php on line 18
```

Whats the right code for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work there. The `$this` that you would want to use there is a controller instance and that is not created yet when the standard `application/config/config.php` loads.

You can try to add a [`pre_system` hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) (that's loaded right before the config object) and include in some helper function that can be called and return the desired value in the `application/config/config.php`. The usual constants like `APPPATH` will be available then.

If you can make this config variable a constant that can work too (just put the `define()` inside `application/config/constants.php`). Since the config file is just a regular php source file, you can have conditionals here too if you must.

Answer (score 0):

You can just work with the arrays.
In your custom  config file

```
$config['myurl'] = 'myurl.com';

$config['base_url'] = &$config['myurl'];
```

This will change the default base_url once the custom config file is loaded, you can also just reset the base_url element in your custom config, however in my opinion it is not recommended to reset the base url in another config file as later in the project you could lose track of where it is  set, why not set it (and maybe use conditions) in the main config file?